# SEO effect of adding iframes to my website

Tags: seo, iframe

I have 2 websites, in one of them that has a fairly good number of views (50,000 pageview / day) I have added an iframe that shows my other website. I did this a few days ago but my second website ranking is getting worse and worse.

Is what I have done useful?

Is it legal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think showing your other site on your first site will help its rankings? There's nothing to gain by doing this for SEO. Not only is traffic not a ranking factor, but iframes are not SEO friendly so that content is invisible to the search engines anyway.

So this is not useful and could possibly be seen as an attempt to manipulate the search results *because that's exactly what it is*.

If the other site is having its rankings drop it is almost certainly due to low quality content as this is something that is continuing to play a larger role in Google's efforts to improve its search results. You need to determine why the content is considered low quality and address it accordingly.

Comment: my second website doesn't have low quality and I'm not adding it for gaining seo on my main website. I was just trying to make my second website (that is loaded in iframe) gain extra views.

Comment: Who says your second website isn't low quality? I know I hear that a lot from users who websites have very low quality content. Is it original content?

Comment: yes its original, what I was trying to do was to boost its pageviews as it is a new website

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani And there is your problem! It is a new site. The whole iframe idea does not actually solve any problems. The answer is to remove the iframe and build your new site the old fashion way by getting it into search and building backlinks. You can add one link from your established site to your new site, but do not add a link on every page via navigation, sidebar, or footer. That is a significant negative signal. Just add one link from your home page or from another important and well ranked page.